# Readline command is skipping lines

Tags: c#, readline

I'm trying to read data from a `.txt` file and place it in a list of a class instances. While debugging, I noticed that the `ReadLine()` command is skipping lines of the `.txt` file. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how to remedy the situation?

```
string logPath;
string defaultPath;
string line;

OpenFileDialog openLog = new OpenFileDialog();
openLog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";

if (openLog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    logPath = openLog.FileName;
    logTextBox.Text = logPath;
    defaultPath = logPath.Substring(0, logPath.LastIndexOf("\\"));

    StreamReader logStream = new StreamReader(logPath);

    while (!logStream.EndOfStream)
    {
        line = logStream.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're mistaken. I suggest you change this into a console app to make it easier for us to reproduce, and show a sample file and what you see. Also, consider using `File.ReadLines` or `File.ReadAllLines`.

Comment: Why do you think it is skipping lines?  Nothing in your posted code would indicate the behavior you are claiming is really happening.

Comment: Perhaps you have a malformed file? Are all of the newlines in the file consistent?

Comment: I think the ReadLines is ok, because it returns an IEnumerable<string> and the lines are only loaded when iterated.

Comment: Can you provide the source code and the file which gives you this error?